# How to build a correlated subquery?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have something like:

```
create (:ex {name: "x", ver: 1.0});
create (:ex {name: "x", ver: 1.1});
create (:ex {name: "y", ver: 0.9});
```

and want to return the latest version for any given name i.e. `x-1.1` and `y-0.9`. I've tried this:

```
match (n:ex), (m:ex) where m.name = n.name and m.ver = max(n.ver) return m
```

but neo hates me with:

> Invalid use of aggregating function max(...) in this context (line 1, column (x) (offset: 61))

what's the correct approach here?

*** Edit I ***

I did also try stringing my versions together:

```
create (:ex {name: "x", ver: 1.0})-[:PrecededBy]->(:ex {name: "x", ver: 1.1});
match (n:ex {name: "x", ver: 1.1}) create (n)->[:PrecededBy]->(:ex {name: "x", ver: 1.2});
create (:ex {name: "y", ver: 0.9});
```

thinking I could use `endNode()` but that doesn't seem to work at all:

```
match (n:ex)-[r]-() return endNode(r)
```

returns 3 nodes!

*** Edit II ***

I might have thought something like this might have worked:

```
match p=(:ex)-[*]->(:ex) return last(nodes(p))
```

but clearly I don't understand `last()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [aggregation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_aggregating_information) functions like `MAX()` and `COLLECT()` (which are only valid in `WITH` and `RETURN` clauses), you can also specify one or more non-aggregating "grouping keys" in the same clause.

For example, to get the maximum version (`max_ver`) for every distinct `name` (the "grouping key"):

```
MATCH (n:ex)
RETURN n.name AS name, MAX(n.ver) AS max_ver;
```

[UPDATED]

On the other hand, if you want to get the *node* with the maximum version for each name, here is one way to do that:

```
MATCH (n:ex)
WITH n
ORDER BY n.ver DESC
WITH n.name AS name, COLLECT(n) AS ns
RETURN name, ns[0] AS latest;
```

This query orders all the nodes by descending version number, collects the nodes with the same name (maintaining the order), and returns a row with each name and the node having that name with the highest version number.

Comment: but how do I return the node instead of the property? how are queries nested? `match (n:ex) where n.ver = (match (m:ex) where m.name = n.name return max(m.ver)) return n` -- or something like that?

Comment: I might have been more precise in my question.  when I said "want to return the latest version" I meant "want to return the node with the latest version"

Comment: awesome! I tried it and it works.  need to read more about `collect`